# Using System.Text.Json to ignore default values for bool data type, only

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, system.text.json

Is there a way at a global level to ignore all and only bools when returning false with System.Text.Json?

I know there's this global condition, but I still need other default values to return.

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
           {
                DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
            };
```

Ideally would not like to add the following to all propeties individually..
`[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a custom JsonConverter for all types, because then you'll have to reinvent the wheel to serialize whole thing. You also can't use a `JsonConverter<bool>` (or `<bool?>`), because you *have* to write a value in its `Write()` method.

So register a `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` with a custom `Modifiers` action that only serializes bools when their value equals true:

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers =
        {
            jsonTypeInfo =>
            {
                foreach (var p in jsonTypeInfo.Properties)
                {
                    if (p.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || p.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                    {
                        p.ShouldSerialize = (containingObject, propertyValue) =>
                        {
                            return propertyValue as bool? == true;
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

From [MS Learn: Customize a JSON contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/En-Us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts). Works since .NET 7.

Answer (score 2):

In **[.NET 7 and later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization)** you can use a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to customize your type's [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) to skip serialization of `bool` properties whose value is false.

First define the following modifier:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    static Func<object, object?, bool> ShouldSerializeBool { get; } = static (obj, value) => (value is bool b ? b : true);

    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> IgnoreFalseBoolProperties { get; } = static typeInfo => 
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;
            foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    if (property.ShouldSerialize is {} shouldSerialize)
                        property.ShouldSerialize = (o, v) => ShouldSerializeBool(o, v) && shouldSerialize(o, v);
                    else
                        property.ShouldSerialize = ShouldSerializeBool;
                }
        };
}
```

And now if your model looks like, e.g.:

```
public record Model(bool BoolValue, int IntValue, bool? NullableBoolValue);
```

When you serialize a model with default values using the modifier:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.IgnoreFalseBoolProperties },
    },
    // Others as required
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Model(default, default, default), options);
```

The false `bool` property will be skipped:

```json
{"IntValue":0,"NullableBoolValue":null}
```

But when serialized with a true `bool` value:

```
var json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Model(true, default, default), options);
```

You will get:

```json
{"BoolValue":true,"IntValue":0,"NullableBoolValue":null}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2wUfY).