# JSON serialization with and without private properties

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

There is a book class with public and private properties:

```
public class Book
{
    private int ID { get; set; } = -1;
    private string? BaseName { get; set; } = null;

    public string? Title { get; private set; } = null;
    public string? Author { get; set; } = null;
}
```

I need the ability to serialize both including private properties and without them.

`JsonSerializerOptions` does not support this option.

Other serializers are model-bound: above each model property, I need to specify whether the property should be serialized but I need to manage this after the program has run.

The only solution I see is converting one model with private properties to another that makes these properties public, but this way I create a lot of duplicate classes.

Comment: How do you determine at runtime when to include or not those properties? Also, can you use .NET 7?

Comment: I need to get json for the client (without private properties) and in order to be able to save the data to the server (with private properties). project on .NET 6

Comment: That answered neither of my questions. So you save the model's JSON serverside _and_ you want to expose the same model's serialized representation to the client? _How_? You can pass different JsonSerializerOptions to ASP.NET Core and to your own serializer. As for .NET 7, you can write [custom modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273639/using-system-text-json-to-ignore-default-values-for-bool-data-type-only/76273891#76273891), but that won't seem to help in that scenario. Anyway the most maintainable solution would still be to have different model classes, one for each scenario.

Comment: Yes, I want to operate on one model, but in one case, I want to hide private properties. I know about the ability to pass different JsonSerializerOptions when serializing, but the JsonSerializer cannot display hidden model properties

Comment: Well you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869393/get-net-core-jsonserializer-to-serialize-private-members) but you shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to serialize your private property (there is [way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869986/9482050) but not likely to use), instead you only need a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to hide your data from your client

```
public class BookDto
{
    public string? Title { get; set; } = null;
    public string? Author { get; set; } = null;
}
```

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; } = -1;
    public string? BaseName { get; set; } = null;

    public string? Title { get; private set; } = null;
    public string? Author { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Comment: I think that only this option is suitable, but the problem is that now there are about 10 models and for each model it will be necessary to create an DTO.

Comment: Actually, you should transfer all your object as  DTO to have more control on it, you can use [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to facilitate your work

Comment: This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) can help you to get the idea of DTO